# After calculating the pay for an employee, add it to the list created in step #1 above(lstPay)(add only the pay)

Tags: python

#create an EMPLOYEE object to store the name, hours worked, and hourly wage by passing them into the constructor. Be sure that the constructor prints the employee name, hours worked, and hourly wage. Then invoke the method that will calculate the employee’s pay.  **

After calculating the pay for an employee, add it to the list created in step #1 above(lstPay)(add only the pay).

my code:

```
# STEP 2

class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, Name="", Hours="", Wage=""):
        self.employeeName = Name`enter code here`
        self.employeeHoursWorked = int(Hours)
        self.employeeHourlyWage = float(Wage)

    def Name(self):
        print("Employee Name: ", self.employeeName.title())

    def HoursWorked(self):
        print("Hours worked: ", self.employeeHoursWorked)

    def Wage(self):
        print("Hourly wage: ", self.employeeHourlyWage)

    def getEmpname(self):
        return self.employeeName.title()

    def setEmpname(self, epName):
        self.employeeName = epName

    def Emppay(self):  # will calculate the employee pay based on info provided

        if self.employeeHoursWorked <= 40:
            print("Employee Pay :", self.employeeHoursWorked * self.employeeHourlyWage)
        else:
            print("Employee Pay :",
                  ((self.employeeHoursWorked - 40) * (self.employeeHourlyWage * 1.5)) + (self.employeeHourlyWage * 40))
        Empname = property(getEmpname, setEmpname)

# STEP 3
print()
strEmpName = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
intHoursWorked = int(input("Enter hours worked: "))
fltHourlyWage = float(input("Enter hourly wage: "))
objEmployee = Employee(strEmpName, intHoursWorked, fltHourlyWage)  # the object objEmployee
objEmployee.Name()
objEmployee.HoursWorked()
objEmployee.Wage()
objEmployee.Emppay()
```

Comment: Sounds like an assignment. Can you please write, where you are stuck?

Comment: After calculating the pay for an employee, add it to the list created in step #1 above(lstPay)(add only the pay).   Now repeat steps 3 and 4 (asking or employee information, create an object, calculate the pay, and add it to the list.  Keep repeating steps 3 and 4 until the user is done entering employee data.  In other words, set up a loop that repeats steps 3 and 4 until the user is done.  You may do this by asking the user to enter an employee name or press the ENTER key when done (use a Boolean to control the loop).

Comment: I am stuck on adding the data (pay) to the list and also setting up a loop that repeats steps 3 and 4 until the user is done

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
employees= list()
while True:
    print()
    strEmpName = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
    if strEmpName.strip() == '':
        break
    else:
        intHoursWorked = int(input("Enter hours worked: "))
        fltHourlyWage = float(input("Enter hourly wage: "))
        objEmployee = Employee(strEmpName, intHoursWorked, fltHourlyWage)  # the object objEmployee
        objEmployee.Name()
        objEmployee.HoursWorked()
        objEmployee.Wage()
        objEmployee.Emppay()
        employees.append(objEmployee)
```

The code above, would ask for employees as long as a name is entered, that is not an empty string and would append the records to list `employees`.

Comment: I would like to keep the code that I posted the same. the issue I am having is how do I append objEmployee.Emppay() into an empty list.

Comment: You can't keep your code and change the logic at the same time. How should that be possible?

Comment: thanks, I used your code and I figured it out. when am done I will post it